# I want to undo my mistakes on firebase blaze charges

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, price

I am developing an app using Firebase as backend.
However, due to my coding mistake, 12.18 million read requests went into FireStore.

This app has not been released yet, and only worked on my emulator.
It's an app that hasn't even been released yet, so I believe it can fix this mishap.

Is there a way to fix this incident, or contact Google?
I'm so scared of how much it will cost

Comment: *firebase here* Sorry that you're having such a stressful experience. A quick check on the pricing calculator shows that 12m reads cost around $6. Aside from that, there's nothing anyone here on Stack Overflow can do about a billing charge like that. I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. --- Going forward, consider using the [Firebase emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) during development, which will never result in any billing charge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebase here*

Sorry that you're having such a stressful experience. A quick check on the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-plan-calculator) shows that 12m reads cost around $7.

Aside from that, there's nothing anyone here on Stack Overflow can do about a billing charge like that. I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Going forward, consider using the [Firebase emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) during development, which will never result in any billing charge

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I contacted Google. Thanks for letting me know about the Firebase Emulator. And I know this question doesn't fit on StackOverflow, but I posted it because there's nowhere else to ask for help. Sorry for posting an inappropriate question.